# mongoose aggregate: output count of field value and total results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want the output to be something like : `[{downVotes : 2}, {upvotes :3}, {totalReviews : 7}]` the total reviews are the reviews matched by `$match`. Some users don't vote.

an example of one of the reviews:

```
 { _id: 584b5d633ac18451ddc4b2c6,
   companyName: 'napacabs.com',
   shortId: 'B1MrpR_Qe',
   updatedAt: Sat Dec 10 2016 16:18:29 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
   anonId: 584b5d39f371067019df86e9,
   myUpdate: Fri Dec 09 2016 20:43:50 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
   statements: [ [Object], [Object] ],
   vote: 'down',
   reviewText: 'Another B1MrpR_Qe',
   __v: 0,
   createdAt: Fri Dec 09 2016 20:41:50 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
   usefulness: { useful: [], useless: [] },
   usefulnessResults: { useful: 0, useless: 0 },
   createdString: 'Fr, December 9th 16, 8:41:50 pm',
   momented: '20 hours ago',
   updatedString: 'Sa, December 10th 16, 4:18:20 pm' }
```

There might be 7 reviews. The vote field value changes depending on how the users vote.

I was able to group by votes but I did not know how to get the total reviews without depending on the vote value.

Also I would like to do some other aggregation on the statements field like get the value from object and aggregate. So I need to understand how to go back and do other aggregation steps and not just funnel it all down to fewer elements.

```
var sendDataToReviewForPage = function(nameOfCompany){
    return Review.aggregate([
            {$match : {companyName : nameOfCompany}},
            // {$unwind : "$createdString"},
            {$group : {_id : "$vote", type : {$push : "$vote"}}},
            {$project : {size : { $size : "$type" }}}
    ]);
};
```

I know the above code doesn't produce the results I wanted but I got a separation of the vote type I got something like `[ { _id: 'down', size: 1 }, { _id: 'up', size: 1 } ]` please help me get to final desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your question with some dummy data.

**Data**

{
    "votes" : "down",
    "company" : "abc",
    "review" : 1
}
{
    "votes" : "down",
    "review" : 2,
    "company" : "xyz"
}
{
    "votes" : "up",
    "review" : 3,
    "company" : "xyz"
}
{
    "votes" : "up",
    "review" : 5,
    "company" : "abc"
}
{
    "votes" : "up",
    "review" : 5,
    "company" : "abc"
}
{
    "votes" : "up",
    "review" : 5,
    "company" : "abc"
}
{
    "votes" : "down",
    "review" : 5,
    "company" : "xyz"
}

Below is my query for returns your expected output.

```
db.getCollection('votes').aggregate([
    {$match : { "company" : "abc"}},
    {
        $group :{
            _id : "null",
            "downVotes" : { $sum : { $cond : [ { $eq : ["$votes" , "down"] }, 1 ,0 ] } },
            "upVotes" : { $sum : { $cond : [ { $eq : ["$votes" , "up"] }, 1 ,0 ] } },
            "totalReviews":{ $sum : "$review"}               
        }
    }
])
```

The output of above query is :

```
{
    "_id" : "null",
    "downVotes" : 1,
    "upVotes" : 3,
    "totalReviews" : 16
}
```

Comment: I see how you do it but my data doesn't have the review field. So I was wondering if there is a different way.

Comment: The review field I just added in my data but what field of counts you need in **totalReviews**.

Comment: @jackblank If you want count by the existence of field 'reviewText', you can do this `"reviewCount": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ { "$ifNull": ["$reviewText", false] }, 1, 0 ] }`

Comment: I think the _id field will always be there since each review has to have an id and the `totalReviews` will be the count of the reviews.

Comment: @jackblank  then you just add this  **"totalReviews":{ $sum : 1}** and the output will be **{
    "_id" : "null",
    "downVotes" : 1,
    "upVotes" : 3,
    "totalReviews" : 4
}**